# Binding to DataGrid's ItemSource in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my application I have to display multiple grid controls(I'm using DevExpress) with the same structure on one screen, so I decided to create UserControl for those grids.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.GridUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid">
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl SelectionMode="Row"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="None">

            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.Time}" Binding="{Binding LessonTime}"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.Lesson}" Binding="{Binding LessonName}"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.Classroom}" Binding="{Binding Classroom}"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="False" AutoWidth="True" ShowGroupPanel="False">
                </dxg:TableView>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I want to be able to set ItemSource for this GridControl in my Window's xaml. I know that I have to use DataContext property to do this, but I'm not aware of how to use it properly. So, what is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you mean that your `UserControl` will be used on a Window and you don't want to set the `ItemsSource` in this XAML that you have posted, but in the Window's XAML?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve. My problem is that I have to use several UserControls in my Window, all with the different collections as the ItemSource.

Comment: Of course, I can just create all GridControls in my Window without using UserControl, but it's not the best solution due to a big amount of repeatable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, first you have to add a property to your `UserControl`, which will then be used as the `ItemsSource` for the data grid. This should look like this:

```
public partial class GridUserControl : UserControl
{
    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(GridUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    //constructor etc.
}
```

Another option would be to base your control on `ItemsControl`, not `UserControl` - then you get the `ItemsControl` property from the base class. The rest would work a little differently, though, so I'll focus on the UserControl for now.

Next step is to have the `DataGrid` in your `UserControl` use whatever you assign to the property. Not sure what your namespace is, edit it as needed. I'm only listing the relevant parts here:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.GridUserControl"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">
    <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:GridUserControl}}" />

</UserControl>
```

Then, on your window, you can use it like this (again, relevant parts only):

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Window1"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">
    <Grid>
        <local:GridUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}"></local:GridUserControl>
        <local:GridUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}"></local:GridUserControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This assumes that your Window's `DataContext` is an object that has relevant `Items1` and `Items2` properties.