# How to call a userControl(child) in another UserControl(Container)

Tags: c#, wpf

Now I have a WPF project that contains other classes and UserControls , now I am stuck!
as you can see bellow the xaml file that I have contains 2 blocks that are similar with different datas (Inputs and outputs)

```
 <!--Block 1-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Header="Inputs">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                    <DataGrid x:Name ="GridI"  Style="{x:Null}"
                    ItemsSource= "{Binding input_List}"

                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}"
                  Margin="5,0" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" RowHeight="50" Height="Auto">


                        <DataGrid.Columns>

                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40*" Binding="{Binding label}">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock  Text="Input"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn  Width="40*" Binding="{Binding type}">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock  Text = "Type"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>


                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="20*">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                    <TextBlock Text="value" />
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
          //datas
                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>

        </StackPanel>

    </GroupBox>

    <!--Block 2 : outputs-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Header="Outputs">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" >

                    <DataGrid x:Name ="GridO"  Style="{x:Null}"
                    ItemsSource= "{Binding output_List}"

                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}"
                  Margin="5,0" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" RowHeight="50" Height="Auto">


                        <DataGrid.Columns>

                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40*" Binding="{Binding label}">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock  Text="Input"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn  Width="40*" Binding="{Binding type}">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock  Text = "Type"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>


                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="20*" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                    <TextBlock Text="value" />
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>

                                              //Datas

                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
    </GroupBox>
```

what I want to do is to create an other UserControl (child) my project in which I will write the code of only one block and this UserControl (child) will be called in the parent UserControl two times (it's kind of code optimazation)

[**This Image can explain more**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3EnJ.png)

Can you please help me how to do this as I am new to WPF 
Is there any C# code that must be added or i can do this only with xaml
Is any modification must be added to my APP.xaml
And thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. Before adding eventually an answer, check if this work for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399129/binding-to-datagrids-itemsource-in-usercontrol

Comment: @DanieleSartori I tried this but No, that's not what I'm asked to do (this is not my choice this is boss's choice) he asked for an UserControl that have the structure of a datagrid (Child UC) that can be called in other UserControls I have been stuck for 7 days now :/

Comment: That's exactly what that question answer. The 2 GroupBox has the same exact structure, except for the fact that they have different item source. You can simple create a usercontrol in a directory of your project, with a custom dependency property callled ItemSource (like the answer in my link), and in your parent window just place it inside a container (a grid, a border or whatever you want)

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to work out from your picture and code what this usercontrol will be. In principle, you just create a new usercontrol, add two of them and bind to either the same or different properties depending on what they/it are to do.

Now in visual studio when you create a window or usercontrol it adds a local:xmlns for you. 
If you add your new usercontrol ( call it SharedUC ) in the same namespace then you can use it anywhere in xaml like:

```
  <local:SharedUC DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty}"
```

You can then use two different properties for datacontext of the two instances. Or the same.

That property can be a complex type.
So you could then have Description or whatever as a property of the object presented as datacontext. Your usercontrol could then bind to Description to show a string in a textblock.